# Is there a way to accelerate matrix plots?

Tags: multithreading, r, optimization, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

`ggpairs()`, like its grandparent `scatterplotMatrix()`, is terribly slow as the number of pairs grows. That's fair; the number of permutations of pairs grows factorially.

What isn't fair is that I have to watch the other cores on my machine sit idle while one cranks away at 100% load.

Is there a way to parallelize large matrix plots?

Here is some sample data for benchmarking.

```
num.vars <- 100
num.rows <- 50000
require(GGally)
require(data.table)

tmp <- data.table(replicate(num.vars, runif(num.rows)),
                  class = as.factor(sample(0:1,size=num.rows, replace=TRUE)))

system.time({

    tmp.plot <- ggpairs(data=tmp, diag=list(continuous="density"), columns=1:num.vars,
                        colour="class", axisLabels="show")
    print(tmp.plot)})
```

Interestingly enough, my initial benchmarks excluding the `print()` statement ran at tolerable speeds (21 minutes for the above). The print statement, when added, caused what appear to be segfaults on my machine. (Hard to say at the moment because the R session is simply killed by the OS).

Is the problem in memory, or is this something that could be parallelized? (At least the plot generation part seems amenable to parallelization.)

Comment: Have you considered if the resulting plot is something sensible? Also, you shouldn't use `replicate` like this (it's an R loop under the hood). Use something like `matrix(runif(num.vars*num.rows), ncol=num.vars)`. The `print` results in actual plotting (i.e., evaluating/rendering the graphical object), which isn't done inside functions for grid graphics otherwise.

Comment: Whoops! You're right, replicate should not be in the benchmark. I added the `print` statement specifically to break up the work, but is it unclear the way I asked? (The resulting plot is sensible if scaled properly ;) although a simple chunking function for this kind of thing would be nice--I have a kludge somewhere that needs a rewrite.)

Comment: Of course parallelizing may help a bit, but if you want a serious improvement, it may be a better way to work smarter, not harder. I can't give you the solution, but perhaps [this solution for MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40790-plot-big) can be a source of inspiration.

Comment: Noooo! Not MATLAB! Just kidding, the strategy outlined there actually seems like a great way to have your cake and eat it too with plots of large data sets.

Comment: Maybe one of the hexagon-binning plot tools, just to reduce the number of items plotted?  `ggplot2::stat_binhex`, for one.

Comment: You might be able to aggregate or simplify your data using tools from the bigvis package `library(devtools); install_github("bigvis")`.  Similar strategy to the MATLAB idea.

Comment: Those are all nice solutions, but it takes a lot of work to modify the standard plot types `ggpairs` accepts. `lower=list('density')` is the closest included option. You can also `putPlot` by column and row, but then, what's the point if you replace every single plot you just made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drawing `ggpairs` plots is single threaded because the bulk of the work inside `GGally:::print.ggpairs` happens inside two for loops (somewhere around line 50, depending upon how you count lines):

```
for (rowPos in 1:numCol) {
    for (columnPos in 1:numCol) {
```

It may be possible to replace these with calls to `plyr::l_ply` (or similar) which has a `.parallel` argument.  I have no idea if the graphics devices will cope OK with several cores trying to simultaneous draw things on them though.  My gut feeling is that getting parallel plotting to work robustly may be non-trivial, but it could also be a fun project.

Comment: Well, one simple idea is to use the parallel `foreach` and at least see what happens, I guess.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander Yes, the `.parallel` argurment to the `plyr` functions calls `foreach`.